# Linq to Entities SqlFunctions.DatePart

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

This code is producing an error:

```
void GetLog()
{
    List<CAR_STATUS_LOGS> logs = null;
    using (TESTEntities ctx = new TESTEntities())
    {
        logs = 
            ctx.CAR_STATUS_LOGS
                .Where(a => SqlFunctions.DatePart("DAY", a.TIMEMARK) == 1)
                .ToList();
    }
}
```

The error is this:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32] DatePart(System.String, System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

I can't see what I am doing wrong with the `SqlFunctions.DatePart`. The column TIMEMARK is a Sqlserver DateTime type.
Any ideas?

Comment: this is a runtime error, not a compile time error, right ?

Comment: Yes this is a runtime error it compiles ok.

Comment: Could you maybe look at the results,  if you do (instead of the Where) : `.Select(a => SqlFunctions.DatePart("day", a.TIMEMARK)).ToList()`

Comment: Unfortunately it returns the same run time error as before.

Comment: And it's clear that you  have an Sql Server db behind this ? Not another db ?

Comment: SqlServer 2008 r2 and .net4.5  and EF 6

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus what is the use for null check of TIMEMARK I mean the second argument is nullable in datepart I guess

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if a.TIMEMARK is a datime, you cann access the day with a.TIMEMARK.Day

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't make sense, look at msdn for SqlFunctions : `Provides common language runtime (CLR) methods that call functions in the database in LINQ to Entities queries.` : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I would rather say that TestEntities is a "mocked" context, or something like that, not related to a db (but than, the error message is not clear).

Comment: Sorry, my answer was not accurate. 
It is partly due to the provider.
For example, the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess provider not support it in every way that I have tried so far.

Comment: Incorrect answer, see bellow the namespace System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlFunctions

Comment: Mark down because Linq to Entities __does__ support `SqlFunctions` in the namespace `System.Data.Entity.SqlServer`

Comment: This is clearly a bad answer. Please at least correct it or refer the answer of @Alexandre .

Answer (score 15):

You can use System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlFunctions from assembly EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll (Entity Framework 6.1.3), example:

```
myTable.Where (w => 
    (System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlFunctions.DatePart("weekday", w.Data).Value == 1);
```

Comment: The best part of this answer is System.Data.Entity.SqlServer  other [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487164(v=vs.110).aspx) refers to System.Data.Object.SqlClients which will compile but will throw an error.

Comment: I had to use: `BeginDate = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)proj.Dt_ProjApply_Begin.Value.Month) + "/" + SqlFunctions.DateName("dd", proj.Dt_ProjApply_Begin) + "/" + SqlFunctions.DateName("yyyy", proj.Dt_ProjApply_Begin)` to get 1/1/2001. But I needed this using at the top to use SqlFunctions: `using System.Data.Objects.SqlClient;`

Answer (score 0):

```
DbFunctions.DiffDays(Date1,Date2)==1
```

Answer (score -1):

write day instead of DAY

```
SqlFunctions.DatePart("day", a.TIMEMARK) == 1).ToList();
```

because day stands for

> dd, d

for more details :-

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datepart.asp

Comment: That will not run either.